# Android: Enable suggestions programmatically on a SearchView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Hello I'm using this example provided by ActionBarSherlock 4.3.1 demo. What I want to do is to set the search view in order to show suggestions only when there are 0 characters inserted and let suggestions disappear when the user write something. How can I do this? Thanks

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;

public class SearchViews extends SherlockActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    SearchView.OnSuggestionListener {

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {
        BaseColumns._ID,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
};

private SuggestionsAdapter mSuggestionsAdapter;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countries…");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);

    if (mSuggestionsAdapter == null) {
        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
        cursor.addRow(new String[]{"1", "'Murica"});
        cursor.addRow(new String[]{"2", "Canada"});
        cursor.addRow(new String[]{"3", "Denmark"});
        mSuggestionsAdapter = new SuggestionsAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), cursor);
    }

    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSuggestionsAdapter);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(R.string.search_views_content);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You searched for: " + query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
    Cursor c = (Cursor) mSuggestionsAdapter.getItem(position);
    String query = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Suggestion clicked: " + query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}

private class SuggestionsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public SuggestionsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view;
        final int textIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);
        tv.setText(cursor.getString(textIndex));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What version of ABS do you use? I've seen in last version (4.3.1) they made some fixes to the suggestions in SearchView.

Comment: I'm using the last version 4.3.1